How to ensure that dependencies are not missing when using pnpm & tsc?
I have a project that uses pnpm and tsc. I've noticed that if I don't change the source code but I tamper with the dependencies then tsc will not rebuild the project only when I change the actual source code.
Example:
package.json:
{
    "name": "@my/lib",
    "private": true,
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "type": "module",
    "exports": {
        ".": "./src/index.ts"
    },
    "scripts": {
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "effect": "3.1.4"
    }
}


src/index.ts:
import { Effect } from "effect";

tsconfig.json:
{
    "extends": "@config/typescript/workspace.json",
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "composite": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationMap": true
    }
    "include": [
        "src"
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "tsBuildInfoFile": ".tsbuildinfo/src.tsbuildinfo",
        "rootDir": "src",
        "outDir": "build/src"
    }
}

If I build this project with pnpm install && tsc --build --verbose tsconfig.json then it compiles successfully. If I don't change the source code, but I remove the effect dependency, then it still compiles because tsc doesn't detect the change. How can I fix this issue?

Maybe effect is still installed as a transitive dependency of an other package. Is it still listed in the package-lock.json?

No, the problem is that tsc sees that I didn't touch the source code so it skips compilation (it doesn't check if I moved dependencies around). The question is how do I  make tsc check if I broke the built with a dep change.

Tried to replicate your observation - my build fails after removing a dependency (though with npm, not pnpm). Tried also with the incremental option, because I thought, that it could be some kind of optimization/caching issue. Did you set "node_modules" in the excludeDirectories option? Though, it should have only an effect, if the watch mode is used.
